# Applying Keys to PHP Array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, mongodb

I am having an issue formatting a return array so that I can upload it into the right format for MongoDB. This is a decoded JSON response using Yahoo Gemini API for Custom Reporting.

In the return array, I get a response separates out the Field Names from the Values like so:

```
{
   "fields": {
     "0": {
       "fieldName": "Day",
       "fieldType": "DIM" 
    },
     "1": {
       "fieldName": "Impressions",
       "fieldType": "FACT" 
    },
     "2": {
       "fieldName": "Clicks",
       "fieldType": "FACT" 
    },
     "3": {
       "fieldName": "Spend",
       "fieldType": "FACT" 
    } 
  },
   "rows": {
     "0": {
       "0": "2015-09-30",
       "1": 17,
       "2": 9,
       "3": "19.35926" 
    },
     "1": {
       "0": "2015-10-04",
       "1": 7,
       "2": 0,
       "3": "0" 
    },
     "2": {
       "0": "2015-10-05",
       "1": 16,
       "2": 7,
       "3": "27.988524" },
```

I want to be able to format this to be in the following format:

```
{
   "rows": {
     "0": {
       "Date": "2015-09-30",
       "Impressions": 17,
       "Clicks": 9,
       "Spend": "19.35926" 
    },
     "1": {
       "Date": "2015-10-04",
       "Impressions": 7,
       "Clicks": 0,
       "Spend": "0" 
    },
```

etc...etc...

Can someone help me out on how to do this? I imagine it is some type of mixture between a "for each" statement as well as a "array_fill_keys", but I haven't been able to figure it out. If someone could point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: When you're building, could you switch/case the 0,1,2,3 reference and create the key at that point w/ the appropriate value?